# useEffect initiates again although dependencies do not change, when url is changed

Tags: react-hooks

My app has two pages. In one of them I initiate a dispatch inside a useEffect hook, so the hook would triger when a Array is changed. But this hook triggers every time when I change url.

This dispatch should add new element to a history Array and it adds new element with a last roll results every time an url is changed.

```
useEffect(() => { dispatch(addNewHistoryAC(rolledDices)) }, [rolledDices])
```

I actualy have no idea how to solve this issue, I am a noob at coding) Should I add some more info to this question?

Comment: Are you manually changing the URL in the address bar? If so, then you are effectively reloading the page, and thus the entire React app remounts... any effects will be re-run. Please [edit] to clarify what the exact reproduction steps are you are using to produce the issue.